# Debouncing a Vue Component method with Lodash

Tags: vue.js, lodash, vuejs2

I am attempting to use Lodash's `debounce` on a Vue 2 method in order to only run once a user has stopped typing in an input field, but I am getting unexpected results:

INPUT FIELD

`<input type="text" v-model='filter.user' placeholder="search" @keyup='dTest'>`

METHOD

```
 dTest() {
        const d = _.debounce(() => {
            console.log('hi');
        }, 2000);
        d();
    }
```

However, 'hi' is being logged to the console on every keypress, with a two second delay.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `dTest` to:

```
dTest = _.debounce(() => {
    console.log('hi');
}, 2000);
```

With your dTest, you are creating a new debounce function every time dTest is run. You are meant to create this function only once, like you see above, then call that function every time.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why the shorthand method doesnt work here?

Comment: Thanks for the help!